# Send message to another Computer through Network via CmdLine

Tags: networking, windows-7, command-line-interface, messaging

I would like to send from a server ( Windows 2008 R2) a pop up message to another Computer in the Network (Windows 7). I already enable AllowRemoteRPC in the registry of my Windows 7 system. 
This cmd works if I send a message from my Windows 2008 R2 Server to another Windows 2003 Server:

```
msg /server:vcs.view.local user1 test
```

or even the other way round

```
msg /server:20.1.1.30 user2 test
```

by the time I want to send a message to the Win7 sytem I got this exception:
"Error 5 getting session names"
Pinging to the Win7 IP works fine

Comment: Did you open the command prompt window using "Run as Administrator"? This can make a difference even if you are logged in with administrative credentials (but not the local administrator account) on Server 2008 and above.

Comment: I tried that and It also did not work

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the message to both the users pc AND the users username at the same time.  For instance(from the server 2008 box):

```
msg /server:thepc theuser "This is a test"
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error message "Error 5 getting session names"

Comment: even `msg * /server:thepc` doesn't work for me, unless I target my own workstation

Answer (score 0):

Error 5 getting session names tends to be a permission based issue that occurs when you can't create an RPC session with the remote computer.

I would check to make sure the RPC is running on the remote computer just to be certain.