# Sending message across the network

Tags: networking, windows-7, messaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send message to another Computer through Network via CmdLine](https://serverfault.com/questions/330737/send-message-to-another-computer-through-network-via-cmdline)

In Windows XP, we had `net send`. 
The replacement is supposed to be a command line utility called `msg`.

However when I try to test this using the following command:

```
11:19:50.94>msg abhi /SERVER:LT2400 Hello
```

I get this error.

```
Error 5 getting session names
```

Some information: I am logged onto two computers on the same network. LT2400 is the computer I am sending a message to. Both are running windows 7 professional 32 bit. abhi is my logon name on both computers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure in order to send a message using net send or similar, the group of computer has to be in the same domain or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this only works on Windows Vista or later if the *receiving* computer is configured as a terminal server. The workaround is to find (on the receiving PC) the reg key:

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server`

and set `AllowRemoteRDC` to be `1`.

Comment: That's interesting, but this is the office network and I don't have access to change certain settings in the registry. :)

Comment: Then maybe the sysadmin doesn't want you sending messages to other desktops on his network?